# The composition of a convex function with an integrable function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

If $f$ is (Riemann) integrable on $[0,1]$ and $\varphi$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$, are there any simple or elegant proofs that $\varphi\circ f$ is also integrable on $[0,1]$?

This [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589023) by J. Lu answers the question (and other similar questions) in a bit more generality--basically whenever $\varphi$ is merely continuous rather than convex--but I'm wondering if there's a simpler method here.

Comment: Should clarify this is about Riemann, not Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Now I cannot access the paper, but is it not trivial after looking at the integrability criterion of almost everywhere continuity?

Comment: Yes, it is trivial if you use that criterion, but that seems a bit heavy duty for something like this. I feel like there should be a more direct and enlightening approach. Also, this is just the Riemann integral.

Comment: Hi Zach, It is not clear for me why the scineram comment settle the question. Because of the set of discontinuity of $\varphi\circ f$ is clearly a subset of the set of discontinuity of $f$, but why this is a Lebesgue measurable set ?

Comment: Does it help if $\varphi$ is Lipschitz on every bounded set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not much of answer, but I just want to state that in my opinion the simplest proof of the result is the one the OP has already alluded to:

1. Every convex function $\varphi$ is continuous.
2. If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $\varphi \circ f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable.

The proof of 1) can be found in most "honors calculus" texts (e.g. Spivak).  If anyone wants a link to a proof, please let me know.  The proof of 2) given in the (nicely written, very elementary, expository) [article by Jitan Lu](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Lu99.pdf) cited by the OP works from the "Riemann notion of Riemann integrability", i.e., convergence of the Riemann sums uniformly in the mesh of the partition.  A lot of discussions of the Riemann integral (e.g. Spivak, Rudin) introduce the "Darboux notion of Riemann integrability" -- i.e., the one with the upper integral and the lower integral -- and with this notion the proof is shorter: closer to half a page than a full page.  See for instance the proof given on page 7 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243integrals2.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130728115828/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243integrals2.pdf)), which is taken almost verbatim from Russell Gordon's analysis text.

I suppose it would be of some interest if there were an *even shorter* proof that took advantage of the convexity, but in practice if you are at all interested in theorems like this you are going to want to know that $\varphi \circ f$ is Riemann integrable even for not necessarily convex continuous $\varphi$.

Comment: Regarding point 1, there is this Math.SE Question: [Prove that every convex function is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/)

Answer (score 2):

Jensen's theorem says
$$
\varphi\left(\int_If(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\right)\le\int_I\varphi(f(x))\;\mathrm{d}x
$$
where the measure of $I=1$. However, what you are asking is in the opposite direction and is not true. Consider the functions
$$
\begin{array}{}f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}&\text{and}&\varphi(x)=x^2\end{array}
$$
$f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and $\varphi$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$, but $\varphi\circ f(x)=x^{-1}$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$.

On the other hand, if $\varphi$ were concave and non-negative, then Jensen's inequality insures that $\varphi\circ f$ is integrable.

**Addendumb:** As Pete Clark points out, and as has been shown here, the question must pertain only to proper Riemann integrals not converging improper integrals.

Comment: $@$robjohn: Your $f(x)$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$, so it cannot be Riemann integrable.  It has a convergent **improper integral**, but that is not the same thing and -- evidently -- the result in question is meant to apply to such functions.

Comment: "not meant", I should have said.

Comment: @Pete: ah, okay. So $\varphi\circ f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$.  Not much to show. $\varphi$ is either monotonic or monotonic decreasing then monotonic increasing.  Easy to show that $\varphi\circ f$ satisfies the other conditions for Riemann integrability.

Comment: @Pete: my answer has been so annotated.