# Strictly concave up implies non negative 2nd derivative

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ a $C^2[0,1]$ function that is strictly concave up:
for any $0\leq x<y\leq 1$ $a\in(0,1)$ $f(ax+(1-a)y)<af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$.

How to show that $f''(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in(0,1)$?
Any reference to read the proof of this result?

Comment: The proofs I am familiar with, such as from Schramm's Introduction to Real Analysis, uses the Taylor series approximation.

Comment: Maybe a start would be to show: strictly concave up (and differentiable) implies the derivative is strictly increasing.

Comment: @GEdgar Any hints on how to show that?

Comment: A hint is maybe the pictures here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/615161/442