# Prove that convex function on $[a,b]$ is absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

In the book Roberts, Varberg, Convex functions, on pp.9-10 is proved that

> If $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and convex then $f$ is absolutely continuous on each $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$.

How can this be extended to the case when the domain of $f$ is instead $[a,b]$?

Edit

I wish to prove the following theorem:

> If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and convex then $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(t)dt$.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, if $f$ is convex on $(a,b)$ then it is automatically continuous. 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/proof-of-every-convex-function-is-continuous

Comment: Yes, I know, but some authors by convex function mean Jensen convex function, which need not be continuous.

Comment: I guess it is not true on the whole domain $[a,b]$.

Comment: If you explicitly require the continuity on $[a,b]$, it is okay, the absolute continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$ follows. If not, $f$ could be discontinuous at $a$ and/or $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**  It should be enough to use the case from the book, together with:

If $\phi$ is nondecreasing, then
$$
\int_a^b \phi(t)\,dt = \lim_{\alpha\searrow a, \beta \nearrow b} \int_\alpha^\beta \phi(t),dt
$$

Comment: Does there always exist integral $\int_a^bf'(t)dt$  for convex $f$ ? In general the values $f'(a)$, $f'(b)$ can be in finite for convex continuous $f$.

Comment: But the limit of $f(\beta) - f(\alpha)$ is finite, right?

Comment: Ok, this limit is $f(b)-f(a)$, what is needed. Many thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f\colon (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex. Consider the function

$$F(x,t) = \frac{f(x+t) - f(x)}{t}\quad(t\neq 0).$$

Then $F$ is increasing in each variable. So $F$ is uniformly bounded on each compact subinterval $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$. In particular, $f$ is Lipschitz on $[c,d]$ hence absolutely continuous.

Comment: Thanks, but I need absolutely continuity also on the whole $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Richard: But $f$ is not even defined on the whole $[a,b]$!

Comment: In my question $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$.