# Convexity implies absolute continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

The following is taken from an exam:

> $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex implies $f$ is absolutely continuous (recall $f'$ exists a.e.)

One has local Lipschitz-ness by convexity, but how to show absolute continuity without global Lipschitz-ness?

Comment: But every continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous. I believe $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is absolutely continuous as well, though I just looked up the definition and am not certain.

Comment: @lnth $x^{1/3}$ IS absolutely continuous on $[-1,0]$

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Convex functions on the real line are expressible as integrals of one-sided derivatives.
The ration $k(x,y)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$  is increasing in $y$ on $[x,b]$.
Hence, the right-hand derivative $D_+f(x)$ exists for all $x\in [a,b]$.
In a similar way we  conclude that  the left-hand derivative $D_-f(x)$ exists for all $x\in[a,b]$, and that  $D_-f(x)\leq D_+f(x)$.

Hence the set of points for which is  $D_-f(x)< D_+f(x)$ is countable.

If $f$ is convex  on $[a,b]$, then   then both
$D_+f(x)$  and   $D_-f(x)$
are integrable with respect to Lebesgue
measure on
$[a,b]$, and  $f(x)=f(a)+ \int_a^x D_+f(t) dt=f(a)+ \int_a^x D_-f(t) dt$.

More generally, suppose D is an increasing, real-valued function defined (at least) on $[a,b)$. Define $g(x) := \int^x_a D(t)dt$, for $a \leq x \leq  b$. (Possibly  $g(b) =\infty$.) Then $g$ is convex.

In the book Roberts, Varberg, Convex functions, on pp.9-10 is proved that

If $f:(a,b)\rightarrow R$
is continuous and convex then f
is absolutely continuous on each $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is continuous since it is absolutely continuous. Moreover, $f'$ exists almost everwhere, and is increasing. Thus $f'' \geq 0$ whence $f$ is convex.

Notice that continuity is important since you could move a point on the graph of a convex function upward or downward rendering it nonconvex.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to show convexity implies absolute continuity.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959175/prove-that-convex-function-on-a-b-is-absolutely-continuous) for a discussion on the other direction @lnth

Comment: By local Lipschitz-ness, it follows immediately that for any $a<c<d<b$, $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[c,d]$ (which is essentially what is shown in the link you give). What I ask here is to show absolutely continuity on the whole of $[a,b]$.

Comment: @knth Remark: you have edited your question so many times that by this point my answer doesn't make much sense. This is a very bad practice.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. I think this question may be of interest, since it has not been asked on this forum before.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is not true as stated. In fact, the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x = 0 \text{ or } x = 1 \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$
is convex on $[0,1]$, but not even continuous.

However, if we add continuity (which may only be violated at the end points), the assertion is true, here is a (brief) sketch of a possible proof.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then, by continuity at the end points and convexity of $f$ (which implies some monotonicy around the end points), there is $\delta > 0$, such that the sum of function value differences on $[a, a+\delta]$ and $[b-\delta,b]$ is less than $\varepsilon$ if the subintervals sum to less than $\delta$. On the remaining interval you can argue by Lipschitz continuity.