# Convex envelope of norm 0

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization, cardinals, convex-hulls

In class, we showed that the convex envelope of the norm 0 on vectors, defined as the number of nonzero coordinates, is the norm 1 on the unitary ball for norm 1 and $\infty$.

We also tried to prove that it is the same if we take the unitary ball in norm 2, but we failed, and we now think it is false.

Do you know the solution for norm 2 or in general any p norm?

---

Edit: A convex envelope of a function $f(x)$ on a domain $D$ is a convex function $g(x)$ defined on $D$ such that  $g(x)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in D$ and for every other convex function such that $h(x)\le f(x)$, then $h(x)\le g(x)\le f(x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely but the convex relaxation of any $p$-norm with $0\le p<1$ is the $1$-norm, after that all $p$-norms are convex so I'm not sure I see the point of your question?

Comment: It all depends where you perform such relaxation: the relaxation of norm 0 on all the space $\mathbb R^n$ is the constant fuction zero.

Comment: Please tell your instructor _not to use the term "0-norm"_. The cardinality function is not a norm. (Stepping off my soapbox now.) The original use of the term made it clear that it is an abuse of notation, but now people throw it around like it's no big deal.

Comment: Furthermore: it is _not_ quite the case that the convex envelope of the cardinality function is the 1-norm. Rather, the convex envelope of the this function is:$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \mathop{\textrm{card}}(x) & \|x\|_\infty \leq 1 \\ +\infty & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: How can an envelope of a limited function be infinite?

Comment: Sorry if it's a silly question but what do you mean exactly with convex envelope of norm 0?

Comment: See the edit on the question.

Comment: This constraint troubles me: "for every other convex function such that $h(x)\le f(x)$, then $h(x)\le g(x)\le f(x)$."

For example, let $g(x)=sin(x)$. Then, based on this definition, is there any convex envelop for $g$?

Comment: $g(x)$ must be convex, remember. the convex envelope of $sin(x)$ on the real line is the constant function $-1$.

Comment: I was confused about the definition because I thought you had to perform first the convex envelope, and then the restriction to the ball (I missed the previous comments). That obviously yielded the zero function. You maybe could rephrase it talking about the *restriction* of the $0$-norm to balls

Answer (score 1):

As long as $p>1$ and $n>1,$ and neither are infinite, the answer is definitely no.

Consider this notation:
$$
f_q^p(x) = \begin{cases}
||x||_q & x \in B_p \\
+\infty &\text{else}
\end{cases},
$$
where $B_p = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid ||x||_p \le 1\}.$
Also define the epigraph
$$
\text{epi} (f) = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid y \ge f(x)\}.
$$
Then, what I will prove, which is equivalent to your statement about convex envelopes, is that, for all $p >1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\},$ $$\text{epi} (f_1^p) \not = \text{conv}( \text{epi} (f_0^p) ).$$

proof:
Note that $(n^{-1/p} \mathbb{1}, n^{(p-1)/p}) \in \text{epi}(f_1^p).$
Now, note that $f_0^p(n^{-1/p} \mathbb{1}) = n > n^{(p-1)/p}$ for all $p, n > 1.$
Thus, $(n^{-1/p} \mathbb{1}, n^{(p-1)/p}) \not\in \text{epi}(f_0^p).$

So the question is, is $(n^{-1/p} \mathbb{1}, n^{(p-1)/p})$ a member of $\text{conv}( \text{epi} (f_0^p) )?$
The answer again is no.
To see why, note that $n^{-1/p} \mathbb{1}$ is an extreme point of $B_p$, thus is cannot be written as a convex combination of other points in $B_p$.
Therefore, it is hopeless to look for a collection of points in $\text{conv}( \text{epi} (f_0^p) )$ who's convex combination is equal to $(n^{-1/p} \mathbb{1}, n^{(p-1)/p})$.

Comment: Is it true in general that the convex envelope of a function must coincide with the function on the extreme points of the (convex) domain?

Comment: @Exodd No: The original function may be discontinuous at some (possibly extreme) point, and the convex envelope must be continuous everywhere, and they definitely can't agree at such a point. But this does not invalidate my claim.  The last sentence in my proof can be proved by the separation principle: find a plane that separates the convex set $\text{conv}(\text{epi}(f_0^p))$ from the point $(n^{-1/p} \mathbb{1}, n^{(p-1)/p}).$  I can add this to the proof but I need to think about what the affine equation would be.

Comment: the convex envelope of a discontinuous convex function is the same function..

Comment: @Exodd a "discontinuous convex function" is a contradiction of terms; confer [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/proof-of-every-convex-function-is-continuous](this answer).

Comment: On a closed domain, a convex function can be discontinuous: take $f:[0,1]\to R$ such that f[0,1)=0, f(0)=1.

Comment: Apologies.  I agree that the function $f([0,1)) = 0, f(1)=1, f=+\infty$ otherwise is an example of a discontinuous function that is also convex. I do not think this breaks my proof because, if indeed the convex envelope of $f_0^p$ agrees with $f_0^p$  at the point $n^{-1/p}\mathbb{1}$, then it necessarily disagrees with $f_1^p$ at that point.  This would make separating $(n^{-1/p}\mathbb{1}, n^{(p-1)/p})$ from $\text{conv}( \text{epi}(f_0^p))$ with an affine hyperplane straightforward.