# Prove that if g is a convex function in [0,1], then g is a continuous function.

Tags: calculus

a) Does the following function convex in $[0,1]$?

$f(x)= \begin{cases} & x^{2} \text{ if }x\in [0,1)\\ & 2\text{ if } x=1 \end{cases}$

b) Prove that if g is a convex function in $[0,1]$ then g is continuous in $(0,1)$

My answer for the first problem is that yes,  since $x^{2}$ is a convex function in the interal $[0,∞]$, it should be convex in $[0,1]$

Could you give me a hint on how to prove the second assertion?

Comment: Your first answer is not correct, since you've used nothing about the value of $f(1)$. Had $f(1) = 0$ instead, it would not be convex.

Comment: I see my mistake already, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer is incorrect because you didn't address the fact that $f(1)=2$. If it were the case that $f(1)=-2$, then the function would be non-convex. You've proven that $f$ is convex on $[0,1)$. To prove that it is convex on $[0,1]$ you need to also show that there is no line with endpoint $(1,2)$ that violates the definition of convexity. This follows straightforwardly from the fact that $2>1=1^2$ and the fact that $f(x)=x^2$ is convex.

For the second part of this question, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/proof-of-every-convex-function-is-continuous).