# Can we always find a convex combination of a given set of points to satisfy this condition?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, continuity, convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

Let $F$ be the average of $f(x)$ for $m$ given vectors $x_1,\dots,x_m$, that is,$$
F=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m f(x_i).
$$
Here $f(x)$ is a convex function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

> Can we always find a convex combination of $x_1,\dots,x_m$, denoted by
>   $\bar{x}=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_ix_i$, such that $F=f(\bar{x})$?

The convex combination implies that $\lambda_i\ge0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i=1$.

I am aware of Jensen's inequality$$
F=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m f(x_i) \ge f(\bar{x}),
$$
for $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$ which may or may not be useful in a proof. I also know that $f_{min} \le F \le f_{max}$, where $f_{min}=\min_if(x_i)$ and $f_{max}=\max_if(x_i)$. If there are some counterexamples for the general case, then under what conditions we could find such a convex combination? Is continuity of $f$ a necessary condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ has full domain and is thus automatically continuous (see Rockafeallar's *Convex Analysis*). So the result follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem (connect on a line segment $x_i$ and $x_j$, where these two take on the minimum and the maximum).

Comment: Thanks but I'm not quite familiar with convex analysis. From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/proof-of-every-convex-function-is-continuous) I can see that $f$ is already continuous. I could not find the relevant theorem in Rockafeallar's Convex Analysis book. Could you mention which theorem in the book should I look at (or give a formal reference)? Is $f$ differentiable? I could not find how the Mean Value Theorem can be used to prove the result.

Comment: 1) Theorem 10.1.
2) g(t) := f((1-t)x_i+tx_j)$.

Comment: Welcome to *Convex Analysis*, the most beautiful subject on this planet!