# A finite convex function in $(a,b)$ is continuous. Moreover, $\phi'$ exists except at most in a countable set and is monotone increasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

If $\phi$ is finite and convex in $(a, b)$, then $\phi$ is continuous in $(a, b)$. Moreover, $\phi'$ exists except at most in a countable set and is monotone increasing.

> Theorem 2.8 Every function of bounded variation has at most a countable number of discontinuities, and they are all of the first kind (jump or removable discontinuities).

- How does $(7.41)$ show in particular that $\phi$ is continuous in $(a,b)$? Don't we need to show $D^-\phi(x) = D^+\phi(x)$ as $h\to 0+$? The book shows $D^-\phi(x) = D^+\phi(x)$ at the end of the proof.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @mfl This is Theorem 7.40 on page 157 of Measure and integral by Wheeden and Zygmund. The theorem on page 157 doesn't state that $\phi$ is finite, but since they say $D^+\phi$ is of bounded variation I looked up the beginning of this section on page 154, and they suppose $\phi$ is finite on an open interval $(a,b)$. Also see the comment by Michael Grant on this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258511/426645.

Comment: @mfl The interval here is open, the one in the counterexample is compact, and the compactness plays a role there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of the limit $D^+\phi(x)$ tells us in particular that $\phi(x+h)\to\phi(x)$ as $h\to 0+$. Similarly, the existence of $D^-\phi(x)$ implies $\phi(x-h)\to\phi(x)$ as $h\to 0+$. These together yield that $\phi$ is continuous at $x$.