# How does concavity look like for non-differentiable or discontinuous function?

Tags: derivatives

In my university textbook, it shows that if a function is concave downwards then it's graph looks something like this

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ConcaveDef.png

But what if a function is discontinuous or continuous but non-differentiable. How does the graph look like then?

Or rather is there a concept concavity for discontinuous and non- differentiable function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concave function can be non-differentiable at some points.  At such a point, its graph will have a corner, with different limits of the derivative from the left and right:

[image]

A concave function can be discontinuous only at an endpoint of the interval of definition.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiousity why only endpoints?

Comment: Also by symmetry same goes for concave upwards function?

Comment: (1) see Gerald Edgar's link for a proof.  (2) Yes.

Comment: @William yes it can be proven that the function can't be discontinuous : https://pages.wustl.edu/files/pages/imce/nachbar/concavity.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A concave function defined on an open interval in $\mathbb R$ is continuous there.  See ["Every Convex Function is Continuous"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/proof-of-every-convex-function-is-continuous/615161#615161)

A concave function may be non-differentiable.  But only at countably many points.  It is right-differentiable and left-differentiable.