# Show that the given set is a closed for any $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued function on the domain $[0,1]$, i.e., $$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$$ such that
$$
f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y) \geq \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y) \quad \text{for all } x, y, \lambda \in [0, 1].
$$
This means that $f$ is concave on the set $[0,1]$.

I need to show that the set $C_{\alpha}=\{u \in [0, 1] \mid f(u) \leq \alpha \}$ is closed for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

As per my understanding, I need to show that for any sequence $\{u_n\}\subset C_{\alpha}$ such that $u_n\to u$, $u$ must be in $C_{\alpha}$.

This means it is given that $$f(u_n)\leq \alpha \ \text{for all}\ n,$$ and we need to show that $$f(u)\leq \alpha.$$ But I am not being able to use convexity of $f$ show this. I also tried to do it via contradiction but did not succeed.

Please help how to proceed.

Comment: Does the step 3 of this accepted answer of the following post answer your question? [Is Lower Envelope of Compact and Convex Set always continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3883236/is-lower-envelope-of-compact-and-convex-set-always-continuous) It proves that a concave function $[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is [lower semi-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Lower_semicontinuity).

Comment: Since $-f$ is concave if $f$ is convex?

Comment: Since your $f$ is concave, your $-f$ is convex. And since (by the linked post applied to this $-f$) your $-f$ is upper semi-continuous, your $f$ is lower semi-continuous. You can prove these two implications easily.