# Can I prove that $f$ convex $\implies$ $f$ continuous using a proof by all possible cases of discontinuity, showing contradiction in each one?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, solution-verification

Given the following definitions of a convex function from Spivak's Calculus:

> **Definition 1:** A function $f$ is convex on an interval, if for all $a$ and $b$ in the interval, the line segment joining $(a,f(a))$ and
> $(b,f(b))$ lies above the graph of $f$.
>
> **Definition 2:** A function $f$ is convex on an interval if for all $a, x$, and $b$ in the interval with $a<x<b$ we have
> $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

**First question:** Does Definition 2 mean that $f$ has to be defined everywhere in an interval to be convex in that interval?

**Second question:** Is it possible to prove that such a function is always continuous? If so, how?

**Here is my attempt at a proof.** I'm going to outline the proofs, without actually proving using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ proofs as would be required to be rigorous. If the general idea of each case below is sound, then I think the corresponding rigorous proofs are relatively simple.

Let $f$ be convex. Assume $f$ is discontinuous at some point $a$, ie $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) \neq f(a)$.

My proof strategy is to go through each of the possible ways that $f$ could be discontinuous at $a$ and show that they violate convexity of $f$.

**Removable discontinuities** aren't possible if $f$ must be defined at every point in an interval to be convex.

**Jump discontinuities** aren't possible for a convex function, due to the following two situations:

[image]

In both cases above, the light red line has a slope that is larger than the slope of the blue line, and this violates convexity.

**Essential discontinuities** aren't possible because the slope between any point $x_1<a$ and a point $a+h$ can be made arbitrarily high. Just choose an $h_1>0$ and an $h_2<0$, let the slope between $x_1$ and $a+h_1$ be some value. Then we can always find an $a+h_2$ with a larger slope, violating convexity as in the picture below.

[image: Essential discontinuity]

Finally, consider the case of a **point discontinuity**

[image]

Whether $f(a)>\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ or $f(a)<\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$, convexity is violated.

In all possible cases, $f$ turns out not to be convex, a contradiction.

Therefore, by proof by contradiction, we conclude that $f$ must be continuous at every point.

Is this approach (proof by possible cases of discontinuity, showing contradiction in each one) correct?

Comment: There are more types of essential discontinuities than the one you picture. E.g., $\sin(1/x)$ has an essential discontinuity at $x=0$. Also, handwaving and appealing to pictures can be very misleading.

Comment: Sure, but regarding specifically $\sin{1/x}$, it isn't convex. How does one prove that convex $f$ must be continuous, after all? I'm finishing the chapter about Convexity in Spivak, and to my bewilderment, he hasn't  mentioned anything about the relationship between convexity and continuity.

Comment: It's not possible to prove that a convex function is always continuous since that's not true. Take for example $f :[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ if $|x| < 1$ and $f(x) = 2$ if $x=1$. However I think it's true that a convex function can have at most countable many points of discontinuity.

Comment: Ok, so perhaps continuous on $(a,b)$ instead of $[a,b]$?

Comment: The point isn't that the specific example is not convex, the point is that your diagram does not conver all possible functions with "essential discontinuities", so your diagram does not prove that a function with essential discontinuity is not convex. Right now, all you have is "you cannot have a function that is continuous everywhere except at a single point where the limit is infinity, and you cannot have the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$." That doesn't really prove what you want to prove, though.

Comment: An "essential discontinuity" is a point $a$ where at least one of the two one-sided limits as we approach $a$ does not exist. Having the limit be $\infty$ is but one such situation. You would need to consider *all* possible ways in which you can have an essential discontinuity, and make sure that you are covering all possible cases.

Comment: Agh. Thanks, @Arturo. Will repost.

Comment: Note Exercise 10. Here Spivak asks you to prove that a convex function on any open interval must be continuous ... and asks for a counterexample on a closed interval.

Comment: Great question and nice attempt! See here for a pictorial proof in the case of an open interval: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/prove-that-every-convex-function-is-continuous

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Does Definition 2 mean that  has to be defined everywhere in an interval to be convex in that interval?

Comment: Of course it does. What makes you think it does not? Where in the quantification "for all $a$, $x$, and $b$ in the interval with $a\lt x\lt b$" do you believe there is a hidden clause that allows you to exclude points, and how does the given condition even make sense, let alone hold, if $f$ is not defined at one of those points?

Comment: Just making sure. A function with a removable discontinuity sure can look convex, but you are right, the quantification is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that if $f$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$ or any open interval then $f$ is continuous (Problem 10, chapter 11 Appendix, "Convexity and Concavity", Calculus by Spivak)

**Proof**

We want to show that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=f(a)$. We can do this by showing that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is always an interval around $a$ in which $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

First we show $f(x)-f(a)<\epsilon$ then we show $-\epsilon<f(x)-f(a)$.

**Let $x_0>a$.**

The line segment from $(a,f(a)$ to $(x_0,f(x_0)$ is

$$g(x)=f(a)+\frac{f(x_0)-f(a)}{x_0-a}, x \in [a,x_0]\tag{1}$$

$$g(x)<f(x)+\epsilon \implies (f(x_0)-f(a))(x-a)<\epsilon(x_0-a)$$

Case 1: $f(x_0)>f(a)$

[image]

$$x<a+\epsilon\frac{x_0-a}{f(x_0)-f(a)}=\alpha$$

Since $g(a)=f(a)$ and $\forall x, x \in (a, x_0) \implies f(x)<g(x)$ (because $f$ is convex), then for $x \in (x_0, min(x_0, \alpha))$ we have $f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon$.

Case 2: $f(x_0)<f(a)<f(a)+\epsilon$

[image]

**Now let $x_0<a$.**

Again we have $(1)$

Case 1: $f(x_0)>f(a)$

$$(f(x_0)-f(a))(x-a)>\epsilon(x_0-a)$$

Note that now we have a $>$ because $x_0-a<0$.

Then $x>a+\epsilon\frac{x_0-a}{f(x_0)-f(a)}=\beta$, and note that $\beta<a$.

Since $g(a)=f(a)$, and $\forall x, x \in (x_0,a) \implies f(x)<g(x)$ (because $f$ convex), then for $x \in (max(x_0, \beta), a)$, we have $f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon$.

Therefore, at this point, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an interval around $a$ such that $f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon$.

Now let's consider where $f(x)>f(a)-\epsilon$.

Let $x_0>a$.

Case 1: $f(x_0)>f(a)>f(a)-\epsilon$

Case 2: $f(x_0)<f(a)$

[image]

We start again with the equation for the line segment $(1)$.

$$g(x)>f(a)-\epsilon \implies x<a-\epsilon\frac{x_0-a}{f(x_0)-f(a)}=\alpha$$

Therefore

$$\forall x, x \in (a, min(x_0, \alpha)) \implies f(x)>f(a)-\epsilon$$

Finally we need to let $x_0<a$ and consider two final cases. I won't do them here, as they are totally analogous to the work shown above.

In the end we have shown that for any $\epsilon>0$ we can always find an interval around $a$ where $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

**Why is the assumption of open interval important?**

Let's say we had convexity on $[a,b]$. The proof above is correct to show continuity on interior points of $[a,b]$, that is points for which there are always other points in the interval that are larger than it.

However consider the following situation

[image]

This function is convex on a closed interval, even with the discontinuity at $a$. There is some $\epsilon>0$ such that we can't keep $f(x)$ within $(f(a)-\epsilon, f(a)+\epsilon)$ for $x$ sufficiently near $a$.