# Convex function using intuition alone

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose $K$ is convex and $F(x) = 1$ for $x$ in $K$ and $F(x) = 0$ for $x$ not in $K$.
Is $F$ a convex function ? What if the $0$ and $1$ are reversed ?

I think in both cases, the function is not convex because the set of points above $F$ is not a convex set since we can pick two points such that the line joining them goes outside the convex set.

Is this intuition correct?

Comment: That’s correct but you should say “above the graph of $F$” rather than “above $F$”. And you shouldn’t say “outside the convex set” because the set you’re describing is not convex.

Comment: Some authors **define** a convex function as one whose epigraph is a convex set.

Comment: Maybe an even stronger intuition is that a convex function $\,\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R\,$ must be continuous. But a function which takes only two distinct values and no other  values in between cannot be continuous, and this does not depend on $K$ being convex or not. For the proof of continuity see for example [Prove that every convex function is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/prove-that-every-convex-function-is-continuous), noting the assumption that the domain of $F$ is an open set.

Comment: Generally, convex analysis embraces the infinities. So, if you let $F(x) =+\infty $ for $x \notin K$ and $0$ otherwise it would be considered convex.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following functions defined on $[0,1]$. All these functions takes value $1$ when input comes from $K$ and $0$ otherwise. I am also assuming $K$ is convex. These are all possibilities:

- $f_1:[0,1]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ and $K=\{1\}$. $f_1$ is a convex function.
- $f_2:[0,1]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ and $K=\{0\}$. $f_2$ is a convex function.
- $f_3:[0,1]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ and $K=[0,1]$. $f_3$ is a convex function.
- $f_4:[0,1]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ and $K=\emptyset$. $f_4$ is a convex function.
- $f_5:[0,1]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is not convex if point of discontinuity of $f_5$ is in $(0,1)$.